# Retrofit changing the URL

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I have an issue with Retrofit. It changes the URL I'm trying to access.

My interface is:

```
@GET("/movies/top_rated")
Call<ApiResponse<Movie>> getTopRatedMovies(@Query("api_key") String apiKey);
```

My client is:

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/";
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
public static Retrofit getClient(){
    if(retrofit == null){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

My issue is that the site I want to retrieve data from is

`http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movies/top_rated?api_key=<<your_key>>`

but Retrofit changes it to

`http://api.themoviedb.org/movies/top_rated?api_key=<<your_key>>`

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need to replace:

```
@GET("/movies/top_rated")
```

with:

```
@GET("movies/top_rated")
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it works! Ill put this as the accepted answer in 10 mins when it allows me to.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what Retrofit does with the leading slash on the annotation is `protocol + domain + annotation`. Which, is what you're seeing.

Without the leading slash in the annotation, the path is directly appended to the base URL.

In web design, for example, you'd see similar problems exist in accessing CSS and Javascript resources in HTML.

Comment: I had no idea. Thanks for that!